# can't access apache on docker from my localhost

Tags: apache, docker, localhost

I've been following [this tutorial for beginners about docker](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/getting-started-with-docker.html) which basically instructs you to create an apache container and map a localhost port to the one on the container.
when I try localhost:80 it doesn't connect, although the container is up and running.
I even made a rule in the firewall to allow connection to port 80, but couldn't get connected to the localhost.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what does command `docker logs CONTAINER_ID` show？

Comment: @mainframer didn't know about this before, it displayed "AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"

Comment: Try fixed this apache issue first. Obviously apache would like you to setup an ServerName. Use command `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash` to enter into your container, then follow this article to fix that issue: https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/fix-apache-error-ah00558/

Comment: @mainframer I did this, and added the ServerName as localhost, I also made sure to commit the change to the image and restarted the container, but still get the same error, and the log appends the same error of AH00558", any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac OS X? If so, the address you need is 192.168.99.100:80, not localhost.

Comment: @warmoverflow that solved it!
could you tell me why can't it be accessed using localhost on windows and the IP binding issue ?

Comment: On Windows/OS X, Docker is running inside a Linux virtual machine (Docker Toolbox) with a default IP address of 192.168.99.100. The 172.17.0.3 address is the address of the docker container **inside** that virtual machine. Port binding will bind the port to the virtual machine, not to your Windows.

Comment: please write the comment in the answer section to accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Windows/OS X, Docker is running inside a Linux virtual machine (Docker Toolbox) with a default IP address of 192.168.99.100. Thus, when you use `docker run -p 80:80` to bind the container port to host port, it in fact binds to the virtual machine's port 80. Thus the address you need is `http://192.168.99.100`.

The 172.17.0.3 address is the address of the docker container **inside** that virtual machine, and is not accessible directly from Windows/OS X.

Answer (score 5):

Add a line to your DockerFile before restarting apache.

```
RUN echo 'ServerName localhost' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: It's 2022 and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question as I was looking for a way to bind my local HTTP port (80) to the HTTP port of my container, an Apache container running on Docker Desktop for Windows - through WSL2 (this is important)

I couldn't find a quick and easy way to do this, so I figured it out myself.

What you must do is bind your local port (on Windows) to the port on WSL.

Here is how I did it :

```
$wsl_ip = (wsl -d "docker-desktop" -- "ifconfig" "eth0" "|" "grep" "inet addr:").trim("").split(":").split()[2]
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=443 connectaddress=$wsl_ip
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=80 connectaddress=$wsl_ip
```

You can either create a Powershell Script (.ps1) and run it with Powershell, or copy/paste each command line into Windows Terminal / Powershell running with Administrator Privileges.

What this does is :

1. attach to the "docker-desktop" distribution running in WSL2 2
2. run "ifconfig eth0 | grep inet addr:" to get the local IP address of
   the "virtual machine"
3. parse the result, and use [Netsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http) to
   create a portproxy between port 80 of your Windows machine and port
   80 of your Linux machine. Same is done for port 443. You can easily
   map other ports if you understand what the command is doing.

**More explanation :**

Since Docker for Windows 10/11 uses WSL2, when you expose a port (through docker-compose or with an EXPOSE command in your Dockerfile), it is exposed to a Linux Distribution called "docker-desktop" that is ran with WSL2. For some reason, ports 80 and 443 that are exposed from a container are NOT forwarded to the host.
The official documentation [acknoledges some issues](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/) but their solution is just to use another port (for example, 8080 mapped to 80).

**Issues with this method :**
Each time you reboot your system (or WSL2), the Linux machine gets assigned a new IP and you have to do it again. What you could do is setup a command to run when your container starts that connects through ssh to the host and runs the script, but I'm too lazy to have done it myself.